# Boost thread wait for condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am looking for a way for a thread to wait until a condition is satisified. Something similar to boost::condition_variable. But instead of having another thread notify the current thread, I want the current thread to wake up when the condition has been fullfilled.

What I have now:
is there a nicer way to do this?

```
       int i = 100;//keep connection alive for 500*100 ms (roughly 1 minute)
       while (!tcp_socket.available() && (i != 0)) 
       {
            if(!tcp_socket.isOpen())
            {
                  break;
            }
            i--;
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
        }
        if (tcp_socket.available())//data available to read?
        {
           //read data do stuff

        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html)? It seems a closer fit, at least for your example.

Comment: I think you have two options, poll the variable with a busy loop or push it with the notify method you don't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need *someone* to notify you.

Typically that someone should be whoever does the work that will make the condition you wait for become true. In case of network I/O such as the one given in your example, that someone would be the operating system: You request an operation on a socket which gets executed by the operating system. Once that operation is completed, the system needs to notify your thread that it can continue.

As was pointed out by Jerry Coffin in the comments, [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) provides a powerful abstraction for this scenario so that you don't have to fiddle with system specific API calls yourself.